# How to get a string value similar to the one that is parsed in the TextVisualizer in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, string-decoding

It's maybe a selly question.. but I'm a bit confused and having a problem in the decoding..

**The question is what's the different between this string:**

> ndE9a8MwEIDhv5JNky1Z/ogrbNNCFkPaoS1dy9lRUoOlc3xn6M vnGQIHToU
>   hOBAvA HKgI3TmaPJ1z41Z4XS7z5sDMN6GuhYyU27a4WnznoDFSmIpXoIlyp
>   jjJ9OEbbUnd9lxfHHkBsvt3oyVyStVhmbxBoIOPBWTLcm7en570JUTPNyNjj
>   GOpEi209MXgOoEqySJXhvCfapLlRhWiqNWguD c74m8BiOzMYQvRfDFPZKSE
>   aYrR2xFPg497dHKtSGcZDsAg03KbPBSVvNNu9Euot7t/0ejAxTDO0HXAj509
>   o1vpm3INN9fp1y80Pw==

And this one:

> ndE9a8MwEIDhv5JNky1Z/ogrbNNCFkPaoS1dy9lRUoOlc3xn6M vnGQIHToU\nhOBAvA HKgI3TmaPJ1z41Z4XS7z5sDMN6GuhYyU27a4WnznoDFSmIpXoIlyp\njjJ9OEbbUnd9lxfHHkBsvt3oyVyStVhmbxBoIOPBWTLcm7en570JUTPNyNjj\nGOpEi209MXgOoEqySJXhvCfapLlRhWiqNWguD c74m8BiOzMYQvRfDFPZKSE\naYrR2xFPg497dHKtSGcZDsAg03KbPBSVvNNu9Euot7t/0ejAxTDO0HXAj509\no1vpm3INN9fp1y80Pw==

I copied both of them from Visual Studio for a string.. The first one from the TextVisualizer:

[image]

And the other one from the preview value window:

[image]

**And how can I get the second first one from the second one?**

**Edit: Here is my code:**
This is my code.. Why I'm not able to decode the response?

```
response = response.Replace("\n", "");
var data = Convert.FromBase64String(response);
var decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
string encodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

I'm getting this result!

> ��=k�0�ῒM�-Y��+l�BCڡ-]��QR��s|g�ϯ�d:��@��*7Nf�'\�՞K���3
>   �k�c%6��9�T�"��"\��2}8F�Rw}��@l����\��Xfoh
>   ��Y2ܛ���  Q3�����D�m=1x�J�H��'ڤ�Q�h�5h.�;�o���a�|1Od��i���O��{tr�Hg�
>   �r�<���n�K�������0��u���=�[�r 7���/4?

Comment: Please post the input, before base64 coding.

Comment: I don'y have it actually.. I'm receiving it from a third party [provider](https://rnd.feide.no/simplesaml/module.php/saml2debug/debug.php).

But it is decoded well in this decoder! I don't know the magic there

Comment: Could it be chinese? If so, it's npot UTF8 but Unicode

Comment: I would post this as a new question - the info that it is Saml coded could be helpful. Any chance that the string was garbled anywhere before?

Answer (score 0):

The Linebreaks and all other control signs are printed in the preview value window :) This is the cause the string is longer

> ndE9a8MwEIDhv5JNky1Z/ogrbNNCFkPaoS1dy9lRUoOlc3xn6M vnGQIHToU\nhOBAvA HKgI3TmaPJ1z41Z4XS7z5sDMN6GuhYyU27a4WnznoDFSmIpXoIlyp\njjJ9OEbbUnd9lxfHHkBsvt3oyVyStVhmbxBoIOPBWTLcm7en570JUTPNyNjj\nGOpEi209MXgOoEqySJXhvCfapLlRhWiqNWguD c74m8BiOzMYQvRfDFPZKSE\naYrR2xFPg497dHKtSGcZDsAg03KbPBSVvNNu9Euot7t/0ejAxTDO0HXAj509\no1vpm3INN9fp1y80Pw==

ndE9a8MwEIDhv5JNky1Z/ogrbNNCFkPaoS1dy9lRUoOlc3xn6M vnGQIHToU **\n** hOBAvA <--

I dont know which Encoding to use in your case, but i works by replacing all \n

```
var b64 =
  "ndE9a8MwEIDhv5JNky1Z/ogrbNNCFkPaoS1dy9lRUoOlc3xn6M vnGQIHToU\nhOBAvA HKgI3TmaPJ1z41Z4XS7z5sDMN6GuhYyU27a4WnznoDFSmIpXoIlyp\njjJ9OEbbUnd9lxfHHkBsvt3oyVyStVhmbxBoIOPBWTLcm7en570JUTPNyNjj\nGOpEi209MXgOoEqySJXhvCfapLlRhWiqNWguD c74m8BiOzMYQvRfDFPZKSE\naYrR2xFPg497dHKtSGcZDsAg03KbPBSVvNNu9Euot7t/0ejAxTDO0HXAj509\no1vpm3INN9fp1y80Pw==";

var replacedNewLine = b64.Replace("\n", string.Empty);

var decoded = Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(replacedNewLine));
Console.WriteLine(decoded);
Console.Read();
```

Same result with both of your strings

PS: seems to be a not Default Encoding or crypted text.

Comment: When I try to decode the first one using this debugger.. it works fine, but the second one isn't working!

https://rnd.feide.no/simplesaml/module.php/saml2debug/debug.php

Comment: you have to set Option with linebreaks or something like that, else the linebreaks are part of the string and make the base64 string invalid ... the first one works because the linebreaks are not printed

Comment: As explaination: base64 string cann be created with an Option "with linebreaks" or somthing like this, and the the base64 string has a fixed line length and Looks like your first string IF you parse the linebreaks \n right.

Comment: Thank you S.L. I removed the new line character "\n" but still not able to decode the base64 response. Please check the code in the question.

Comment: This is exactly my problem.. But I wonder what's the magic that this debugger is doing to decode it!

https://rnd.feide.no/simplesaml/module.php/saml2debug/debug.php

Comment: look here maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249199/decode-saml-2-0-64base-string

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misread what your expected output ist.

There is a difference: look for the newline character in the first: "\n". As a guess the Text visualizer is parsing the string in someway and wraps the string at the location of the \n.
As for getting this one: Replace all newline characters ("\n") with string.emptyy or "".

Comment: @Homam i think he means replacing th \n with string.empty

Comment: I replaced it but didn't work.. in my code..
I'll add the code to the question.